# how to resize tabpane inside Vbox

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am new to javafx , just started a practice.
I am working on UI which l'll difficult for me to understand.

- I have taken a splitpane inside which having two anchor pane one in 0
  index and other is in 1 index of split pane. As shown in figure to
  get better idea.

  ```
  Splitpane
      | - > Anchorpane
      | - > Anchorpane
               | - >   Hbox
               | - >   Tabpane
               | - >   Hbox
  ```

  [image]
  Now in the split index 1 area,
- I just want to resize tabpane when user chages the devider position
  and remaining Hboxs will stay as it is
- I tried with tabpane max height setting ,vgrow = always and many more
  things, but not working. Is there any way that i can only bind tabpane
  to parent and grow when parent grow?

Comment: Its extremly difficult to understand what you trying to achieve from your description.I advise you to describe it more detial and in a bit different way , btw my recommendation is ,use Scene Builder , its perfect - Gluon is the company that provides support for it now , you can get it here http://gluonhq.com/open-source/scene-builder/ im sure when you get your hands on it you can create anything its easy to use and you see it on the fly, works with fxml

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code. Any reason why you are using `AnchorPane`s?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:I used by mistake tableView instead of TabPane , bud result is the same either way,**

So i think i know what you trying to do , i opened sceneBuilder and here is the result :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <items>
      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0" />
      <BorderPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
         <top>
            <HBox prefHeight="53.0" prefWidth="598.0" style="-fx-background-color: red;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
         </top>
         <center>
            <TableView prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <columns>
                  <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C1" />
                  <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C2" />
               </columns>
            </TableView>
         </center>
         <bottom>
            <HBox prefHeight="34.0" prefWidth="598.0" style="-fx-background-color: yellow;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
         </bottom>
      </BorderPane>
   </items>
</SplitPane>
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

Is this what you are trying to do?Upper index in split pane is empty , use borderpane there and add another content to your linking

Answer (score -1):

Set your children `setPrefSize` to the max. This will probably solve your problem.